# Differential gene expression analysis in Python

Tags: python, r, bioinformatics, rpy2

It seems that most differential gene expression packages for RNA-Seq are written in R.

```
Examples include:

- edgeR
- limma
- DESeq
```

Are any similar (and easy to use) packages available for Python, or have any of the R packages been ported?

The best I could find was:

- https://bcbio.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/differential-expression-analysis-with-bioconductor-and-python/
- http://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~kshedden/Python-Workshop/gene_expression_comparison.html

But I really don't want to use rpy2 (*1st link*). The second link is probably where I would start, but I first wanted to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: why the downvotes? If you've got a better solution, by all means please post them, but subprocessing out doesn't seem very Pythonic to me.

Comment: Subprocessing is totally Pythonic imho, because Python is a great language for scripting and pipelining. You are trying to make your life harder. Why the downvotes, though.

Comment: possible reason for downvote: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. `

Comment: I took this question over to Biostars, if anyone has the need to further discuss this topic.

https://www.biostars.org/p/9495368/